# Monogame - Music and sound effect not playing simultaneously

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, audio, monogame

I understand this question has been asked before but I'm doing it through **Mono game** and the programming language I'm using is **C#**.

I'm made a game that the aim of it is to go through obstacles and for every obstacle you go through, you earn a point. Now, I'm trying to add the finishing touches. I've added back ground music to the game **but I want a sound to play every time you press the space bar.** So i added the sound into the game and i put it through the pipeline tool, implemented the sound into the code and so on.

But every time I play the game, **the BGM plays but if you press the space bar the sound plays but the BGM stops.** I tried to add the sound as a 'sound effect' but its still playing it simultaneously.

**This is where the sound gets loaded into the game.**

```
Song backgroundMusic; 
Song jumpsound;
```

**This is the part of the code that plays the sound if you press the space bar.**

```
public void Update (KeyboardState spaceNow, KeyboardState spacePrev,Song Jsound) 
    {
        if((spaceNow.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) == true) && (spacePrev.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) == false))
        {
            y -= 50;
            Vertspeed = -10;
           MediaPlayer.Play(Jsound);

        }
```

**Open to suggestions and feedback :)**

**Neamus.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason why the jumpsound should be `Song`? It seems like you should use `SoundEffect` class instead.

It's also possible to play multiple soundeffects simultaneously.

Comment: So if i made the jumpsound a sound effect, it wouldn't interrupt the song.

Comment: Song shoudln't be interrupted. You can even play same sound effect multiple times - which is nice for double-jump for example